# Laravel, Installer Not works

Tags: php, laravel

After Laravel released new version (5.7) of this framework, i cant create new project and its commands not work

i did this works:

1) use `laravel new MyProject` with this error :

> [GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException] Error creating resource: [message] 
>        fopen(http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest.zip): failed to open stream: A 
>        connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly 
>        respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>        connected host has failed to respond.[file]
>
> C:\Users\Saeid\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\
>        Handler\StreamHandler.php[line] 324

2) use `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel MyProject` with this error :

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

3) update composer by `composer selfupdate`  with this error :

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

4) update laravel instller by `composer global require "laravel/installer"`

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

**Notice**: in all of steps all links work on google chrome!!!! but it said "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."
**Notice**: my composer version (1.7.2)
**Notice**: my Laravel installer version is (2.0.1)

Comment: Could you try a `composer diagnose`?

Comment: Check your php.ini and make sure `allow_url_fopen` is enabled (the php.ini for cli).

Comment: 1- allow_url_fopen is "on"
2- composer diagnose has same problem ("  file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. ")

Comment: you are probably from Iran. use a vpn, we are sanctioned

Comment: i did it!! but the problem still alive...
i said can see this addresses and files by google chrome.. without vpn or with vpn... but command prompt i see this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the problem ...

that's "**Composer Proxy Setting**"

because **damned Filtering** in Iran we must use proxy based programs for bypass the filtering.

last time i installed the composer the proxy based anti filter app (freegate) was running and composer get the local proxy address "127.0.0.1:8580" and all of the problems started...

today when the freegate was running i saw everything is **OK**!!!
some body know how to change the composer proxy setting???
i removed the composer and install it again but the installer automatically use this proxy address and disable the checkbox that use to select the proxy setting.

that means i cant disable proxy setting or change it....    :(

Answer (score -2):

first download the composer the open your IDE the execute composer create-project "laravel/laravel" project-name

Comment: This is not a solution to the question. The OP already has composer installed (as verified by the output of the commands). Also, the command you suggested was already tried and confirmed not working in his original question. Also, your answer is really incomprehensible. Download composer, open your IDE then execute composer create-project? Where is the installation step for Composer? Why open your IDE when you can use a terminal? Also, what to open in your IDE when you do not have a project? Please put some more effort in it.